# How access datarow value using Oxygene

Tags: delphi, oxygene

The following line of code generates the compile time error (PE19) There is no overloaded method "get_item" with 0 parameters.  Any idea on how to access the data in the datarow using Oxygene?

```
indexValue:=dtIndexValues.Rows[1].Item('IndexID');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
indexValue := dtIndexValues.Rows[1].Item['IndexID'];
```

or

```
indexValue := dtIndexValues.Rows[1]['IndexID'];
```

since Item is the default indexer.